# How strictly does Ryanair enforce the height restriction on baggage?

Tags: luggage, airlines, ryanair

The dimensions of my hand baggage are 59cm x 36cm x 19cm. The width and length are OK, but the height is 4 cm too big (it's 59, but should be under 55). I have heard people say that height is the least important since the boxes they use to measure the bags have an open top.

So I'm wondering if I should just buy a new baggage and not risk it, or do you think they won't fine me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've personally never been caught doing this (with a bag 3 cm too tall) on Ryanair at STN, DUB, SXF, FKB, BSL, CPH, GOT or PDV, and I've flown with them 10 times in 2015 and 17 times since 2017.

But, as always, YMMV. So have cash ready for the penalty fee just in case.