# Ryan air priority baggage

Tags: hand-luggage, ryanair

We are flying Ryan air and have booked priority boarding so we can carry our 10kg hand luggage onto the cabin. 
However - I just measured the bags we currently own and they are slightly bigger on 2 of the dimensions and smaller on the 3rd. 
 On the Ryan Air website it states the bag must not exceed 55 x 40 x 20 
Our bags are 56 x 35 x 22

Are we going to be charged extra or penalised because our bag is 3cm larger than they say it can be? 
Sorry if that sounds stupid but I’d rather know now and buy new bags than get to the airport and be penalised

Comment: Where are you flying from? Ryanair has nothing to do with it in practice, it will all bil down to the local airport staff. I have a good idea of which handling companies have picky staff

Comment: Rest assured no one will bat an eyelid. If you have had non priority something might have happened.With priority boarding they will look the other way or at the worst put it in the hold. They print me a boarding card for free if I ask them, as I pay for check in luggage, when they should really charge me for that.

Answer (score 3):

Because the baggage is larger than allowed, Ryanair may refuse to allow you to carry it in-cabin, require it be transported as hold baggage, and charge you. Ryanair is well-known to be picky about all kinds of things — like local printing of boarding passes, luggage size and weight compliance —  because collecting additional charges makes money for the airline.

On the other hand, sometimes the rules aren't enforced. Read [this SE question, answer, and comments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111809/how-strictly-does-ryanair-enforce-the-height-restriction-on-baggage).

All in all...no one can say. If you're risk-averse, obtain new and conforming luggage. If you carry the luggage you already have, you may stroll on board with no difficulty, but be prepared as you may be charged.

Comment: From personal experience with Ryanair and Wizzair they will rarely check sizes of backpack, but if you have suitcase (especially hard shell one) it's almost guaranteed that they will ask you to check it in the size-checking cage. Then if it doesn't fit, doesn't matter how much bigger it is - you will have to pay.